# Archive Outlook files Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After having some problems with my computer I now have a second profile built which functions well.  :-) I now have 3 Archive folders for some info I really need to keep so would like to merge all the messages into 1 continuing folder so I can access them in the future.  Is there a way to do this.  The folder sizes are 300,000kb 9500kb and 265kb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is software which can do this automatically but a free way is probably just as easy:

Simply add all the `.pst` accounts as Data Files to Outlook. Then simply drag and drop the emails to the 1 location you want.

You don't state which version of Outlook you're on, so I can't give you exact steps but see [Open, change, or close Outlook data files - Outlook - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Open-change-or-close-Outlook-data-files-4ca341f6-a611-4a0b-aca6-fe68c215c145)

If the link dies, try a search in your favourite search engine for `add data file to outlook`